# How can we have 2 parameters in java.util.function.Function lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

We can create lambda functions like this:

```
Function<Integer, String> getLambda = (a) -> new String("given value is "a);
```

I have a scenario where I need to take 2 values in a parameter. How can I accomplish that using Function?

Example:

```
getLamda(10,20); // I know this line will give error. How can I acheive this?
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is done using a [`BiFunction<T,U,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). Following is an example of a `BiFunction` returning the character at the specified index of a String:

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, Character> charAtFunction = (string, index) -> string.charAt(index);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try :

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> lambda = (a, b) -> ("Given values are " + a + ", " + b);
```